# What is the difference between Code written in VB.NET and C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, vb.net-2010, code-analysis

Can anybody tel me the difference by considering all the factors like Execution time,Efficiency.etc

Which is effective ?

Comment: Its 2 different languages using same framework!

Comment: What is the reason for down vote ? I hope its good question for good thinkers and researchers..Even I faced this question in interview.

Comment: I haven't downvote in any case.. But I agree with you, downvoters should give reasons!

Answer (score 3):

VB.NET is a "friendly" programming language.  It supports dynamic programming right out of the box, no need to explicitly type your variables for example.  Data conversions are automatic.  Overflow checking is on by default.  Passing properties by reference just works.  You can assign an int to a byte without a cast.  You can create a multi-window Winforms app without ever really understanding object-oriented programming.  The compiler auto-generates a bunch of code.

None of this comes for free.  In some cases, the extra overhead can be very substantial.  Simply adding two numbers can be three times more expensive than needed, the overflow checking is pretty deer.  Automatic conversions between a string and a number are a frequent wart in a VB.NET program, very expensive.  You don't stand much of a chance to identify such a bottleneck from just looking at the source code.

C# is much stricter, it (almost) never generates code that hides execution cost under the floor mat.  It thus makes it automatically easier to write performant code.  This does not otherwise completely avoid having to use a profiler to identify a bottle-neck.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand upon both answers given so far.  They are both correct.  The problem with VB.NET is typically the developer's mindset AND the flexibility of the VB.NET language.

If you use Option Explicit On, Option Strict On (Option Strict On enables Option Explicit) and do not use Option Infer you will get better results at the expense of more complicated code.  By complicated I mean you have to correctly cast your variables and objects, something that maybe considered complicated for a BASIC developer.

Option Strict Information:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329

Option Infer On, should not be used 99.99% of the time when writing new applications.  I would say 100% of the time, but someone will have a legitimate reason, I just can not think of any.

Option Infer Information:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There should be none, because they both compile down to the same language. The biggest variable factor is the programmer - they may do things in a more roundabout or inefficient way (for example, I can imagine that VB.NET programmers coming from a VB(A) background tend to solve problems differently from C# programmers coming from a C(++) background).

If you want to be sure, take a piece of code and inspect the IL.